# How to split this string by regex?

Tags: regex, scala, split

I have some string, they looks like:

```
div#title.title.top
#main.main
a.bold#empty.red
```

They are similar to haml, and I want to split them by regex, but I don't know how to define it.

```
val r = """???""".r // HELP
val items = "a.bold#empty.red".split(r)
items // -> "a", ".bold", "#empty", ".red"
```

How to do this?

---

UPDATE

Sorry, everyone, but I need to make this question harder. I'm very interested in

```
val r = """(?<=\w)\b"""
```

But it failed to parse the more complex ones:

```
div#question-title.title-1.h-222_333
```

I hope it will be parsed to:

```
div
#question-title
.title-1
.h-222_333
```

I wanna know how to improve that regex?

Comment: Well, what did you _expect_ it to parse? You haven't really explained what are your expectations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you need here but this should help:

```
(?:\.|#)?\w+
```

It means a "term" is defined as an optional dot or hash followed by some word characters.

You will end up with:

```
div
#title
.title
.top
#main
.main
a
.bold
#empty
.red
```

Answer (score 9):

```
val r = """(?<=\w)\b(?!-)"""
```

Note that split takes a `String` representing a regular expression, not a `Regex`, so you must not convert `r` from `String` to `Regex`.

Brief explanation on the regex:

- `(?<=...)` is a look-behind. It states that this match must be preceded by the pattern `...`, or, in your case `\w`, meaning you want the pattern to follow a digit, letter, or underline.
- `\b` means word boundary. It is a zero-length match that happen between a word character (digits, letters and underscore) and a non-word character, or vice versa. Because it is zero-length, `split` won't remove any character when splitting.
- `(?!...)` is a negative-lookahead. Here I use to say that I'm not interested in word boundaries from a letter to a dash.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with Josh M's answer, he has a good regular expression, but since `split` takes a regular expression matching the "delimiter", you need to use `findAllIn` as follows:

```
val r = """(?:\.|#)?\w+""".r
val items = r findAllIn "a.bold#empty.red"
    //maybe you want a toList on the end also
```

Then you get the results

```
div#title.title.top    -> List(div, #title, .title, .top)
#main.main             -> List(#main, .main)
a.bold#empty.red       -> List(a, .bold, #empty, .red)
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't\don't know the specifics of the function in question.

Comment: thank you very much. But since @Josh is the first one who gives me the correct answer, so I decide to accept his answer.

Comment: Note that `scala.util.matching.Regex` has `split` method too.